# Is it possible to add more values to Azure Devops Query Editor?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am creating a query of closed tickets from this quarter, but I have been unable to find a way to add a value that specifies the beginning of the 3 months to the end of the 3 months. Is there a way that I can add a value that asks for a specific date or a value that is @StartOfQuarter?

[image: query editor and value choices]

I need the field value to be State Change Date, but Azure only displays a limited number of values for that field. @StartOfMonth is probably the closest to what I am looking for, but is there a way that I could add a value that is @StartOfQuarter? Or add a specific start and end date? I have been looking around and have not found any ways to do this.